# Run cron-like tasks every few minutes in beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My beam pipeline imports data into bigquery, and recently needs to support updates and deletes. Since BigQuery has daily limits to the amount of updates and deletes I can do in a day, I want a separate process that runs every 30 minutes or so to merge the updates and deletes into the main dataset.

Is there any way to do this with Apache Beam? A function that runs on a timer and executes a side-effect only, and ensure it executes only on one machine?

I would very much prefer it if all my code was in the same dataflow job codebase, and it does not execute if the dataflow job is not running.

Comment: have you looked at timers? https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use [GenerateSequence](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/GenerateSequence.html) transform to trigger an action (merging updates and deletes) at a specified frequency.

Comment: Note that GenerateSequence effectively generates all its values in parallel, without concerns for timings, so is not that useful for performing actions every 'n' minutes.

The .withTimestampFn() option is just for labeling the sequence numbers with a timestamp, it does not affect the frequency. 

Therefore you would have to use windowing and triggering to actually output a sequence value every 'n' minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Otherway, You should use Kubernetes Cronjobs.

Answer (score 1):

Use cloud scheduler to re-launch the pipeline every 30 mins?

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/